# MDI parent controls are not visible when child form is opened in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have two forms. One is a MDI/parent form and the other is a child form. Parent form has a few controls like label, textbox, button, etc. When I click on a button in the parent form, child form is brought in front of the parent form. But all the controls in the parent form become invisible. I want all the controls in parent form to remain visible when I open the child form. How can I achieve this?

```
        MdiClient client;
        Form2 myform;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          

            IsMdiContainer = true;            
            client = Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();
            client.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!MdiChildren.Any(x => x.Visible)) client.SendToBack();
            };    
        }


private void ShowForm(Form childForm)
        {
            client.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();               
        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myform = new Form2() { MdiParent = this };
            ShowForm(myform);
        }
```

Comment: Hello! I have removed the C# tag from your question's title (and fixed a few typos), but looking at your code it seems your indentation is off - feel free to re-edit your post :)

Comment: Just remove the client.BringToFront() call.  Get rid of the GotFocus event handler as well.  The proper way to do this is by docking a panel to an edge of the parent and put controls on that panel.

Comment: @retailcoder : Thank you for editing.But it seems like not much changes you have done.. :)

Comment: @HansPassant : If i remove the client.BringToFront() then i wont be able to see the child form infront of the parent form. "Docking a panel to an edge of the parent and put controls on that panel"- Could you please explain?

Comment: Drop a panel on the parent form.  Set its Dock property to, say, Left.  The MDI client window shrinks to take the remaining space.  Don't cover it with any other controls.

Comment: @Mothy until you have > 2000 rep, *suggested edits* must be reviewed by the community (by users with > 2000 rep). Edits that are too drastic / change too much of a post (especially code) have a great deal of a better chance of getting rejected :)

Comment: @Mothy You could set the `StartPosition` property of the child form to center parent